# How to facilitate lazy loading in Nhibernate while i am using Disposable approach?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, lazy-loading

Currently I am developing the repository for my application, lazy loading give me a great performance push, However its not possible while i am using code block like this

```
    public IList<T> GetAll()
    {
        using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            try
            {
                return new List<T>(session.QueryOver<T>().Future());
            }
            catch (HibernateException)
            {
                throw;
            }
            finally
            {
                session.Flush();
            }

        }
    }
```

since the `session` is disposed after i finish, i will receive lazy loading exception when I try to read the references of my objects in the code.

My questions are:

1. What is the importance of the using block `(using (var session = factory.OpenSession))`,
   why its a bad practice to use single session for all the methods in the repository without flushing it?
2. Is it possible to use lazy loading with the using block ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*What is the importance of a using block ?*

Ref : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

> The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the
>   correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the
>   object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called. Within
>   the using block, the object is read-only and cannot be modified or
>   reassigned.

The `Session` object returned by `.OpenSession()` implements `IDisposable`

*Why is it a bad practise to use single session for all methods in the repository without flushing it ?
Is it possible to use lazy loading with the using block ?*

I don't quite understand the latter part of the question here, `Session` in NHibernate is considered as a **unit of work** and you I believe you need to pick choose a suitable contextual session pattern.

- session per thread
- session per request (in case of web application)
- session per conversation

Reference: http://nhibernate.info/blog/2011/03/02/effective-nhibernate-session-management-for-web-apps.html